# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation (PhraseOMatic)

Tags: java

I tried to run the code from Head First Java as the following:

```
public class PhraseOMatic {
   public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] wordListOne = {"24/7", "mult-iTier", "30,000 foot", "B-to-B", "win-win", "front-end", "web-based", "pervasive", "smart", "six-sigma", "critical-path", "dynamic"};

    String[] wordListTwo = {"empowered", "sticky", "value-added", "oriented", "centric", "distributed", "clustered", "branded", "outside-the-box", "positioned", "networked", "focused", "leveraged", "aligned", "targeted", "shared", "cooperative", "accelerated"};

    String[] wordListThree = {"process", "tipping-point", "solution", "architecture", "cor competency", "strategy", "mindshare", "portal", "space", "vision", "paradigm", "mission"};

    int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
    int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
    int threeLength = wordListThree.length;

    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
    int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);

    String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];

    System.out.println("What we need is a " + phrase);
    }
}
```

and it is here that I receive this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at PhraseOMatic.main(apples.java:2)
```

I see from the error that the problem is in line 2, but I can identify the error

Comment: i compile and run the program  no error occur

Comment: Please post the code along with `package` statement so we can help you out.

Comment: @AVD That appears to be all of OP's code.  Regardless, OP provided sufficient information to solve the issue: class PhraseOMatic is saved in a file named "apples.java".

Comment: I think there is an IDE and may be OP has removed package statement or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at exception trace (`PhraseOMatic.main(apples.java:2)`). Your public class `PhraseOMatic` must be saved with `PhraseOMatic.java` file. Name of `top-level` public class and .java file must be same.

Comment: Rename your .java file to `PhraseOMatic.java`. Do you have IDE (netbeans/eclipse etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at `PhraseOMatic.main(apples.java:2)`. Your file is named `apples.java`, but in Java your files HAVE to have the same name as your classes. In your case `PhraseOMatic.java`.

Answer (score 0):

**your stake trace:**

```
PhraseOMatic.main(apples.java:2)
```

So you are missing to run java to level class; your java main class is PhraseOMatic